# Using Italic string as NSMenuItem's Title

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way, that I can display the **title** of an **NSMenuItem** in *italics*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an `NSAttributedString` with `NSItalicFontMask` applied as a font trait. Set this attributed string to the [**`attributedTitle`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItem/attributedTitle) property of your `NSMenuItem`.